# TypeORM PrimaryGeneratedColumn UUID : Null value in column id on save

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I got a NestJs project with typeORM and a postgresl database. I want to have entity with id as generated uuid. When I save it seems like the uuid is not generated and the entity is saved with a null id.

My entity file :

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { JobStatusEnum } from './jobStatus.enum';

@Entity()
export class Job {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  ...
}
```

My service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Job } from '../model/job.entity';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class JobService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(Job) private jobRepository: Repository<Job>) {}

  create(): Promise<Job> {

    const job: Job = {
      id: null,
      name: 'Job Name',
      ...
    };

    return this.jobRepository.save(job);
  }
  ...
}
```

The error message I get :

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: QueryFailedError: null value in column "id" of relation "job" violates not-null constraint
```

Comment: Did you check if the `id` column in the `job` table has a default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently if I specify that the id is null it doesn't work with uuid generation.

Instead :

```
const job: Job = {
  name: 'Job Name',
  ...
};
```

Or

```
const job: new Job();
job.name = 'Job Name';
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because you have changed your schema but the database still works with the previous schema
You have to delete the table once and recreate it

Comment: I deleted the database and recreated it. Nothing changed